# Read/write block size performance inconsistent result, is my testing accurate?

Tags: performance, io

I'm trying to do some testing in term of file system block size to identify some potential bottleneck in a grid job due to bad IO. 
I notice a lot of small file increment of 8096 B during the job while the block size of the FS is :

```
stat -fc %s /my/filesytem
1048576
```

Which is far from optimal. To simulate such behaviour I've create two small random file of from 1GB to 20GB with `dd` and  `/dev/urandom` as a source, and I tried this python code:

```
#!/bin/python
bsize=8096
print('File random.20g1')
print(strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S"))
f1= open('random.20g1','rb')
f2= open('random.20g1.dest','wb')

while True:
   b = f1.read(bsize)
   if b:
       f2.write(b)
   else:
       break
print(strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S"))
```

And I've tried the same with `bsize=1048576`.

I first observe a small read/write time difference of 4 seconds between a block size of 8096 and 1048576 (4 sec less for the big block size).
This first result was promising but after further testing, like increasing the size of the file to 20GB or doing the same with 10 files of GB I observe always the same difference of 4/3 seconds in term of performance and the gain never scale whatever the file.

Am I doing something wrong in my test procedure or does it seems OK to you ?
I would have expected some improvement in increasing the size of the file for example.

Comment: I haven’t checked the behaviour of your particular test, but I suspect you’re measuring the performance of the kernel’s read-ahead algorithms rather than the performance of varying-sized reads.

Comment: OK that could be an answer though i find strange that there 's a différence but it stays really small even with bigger file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code

```
while True:
   b = f1.read(bsize)
   if b:
       f2.write(b)
   else:
       break
```

is doing *sequential* reads and writes - given any `bsize`, it reads the first `bsize` bytes, writes them to the destination file, then reads the second `bsize` bytes, appends those to the destination file, ...

Your OS will buffer those through [the page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache), and may even do read-ahead and pre-buffer your input data as @StephenKitt mentioned in the comments.  Thus the underlying IO calls to the actual disk will wind up coalesced into much larger chunks, probably the 1 MB you've mentioned.

The small difference you see in performance is almost certainly due solely because when you use a smaller `bsize` your process has to make more system calls into the kernel to actually move the data.

So that's almost certainly why you don't see much difference when you change `bsize` in your test code, but it's not really possible to say for certain without a lot more details about your system.

**MORE...**

What you're doing is effectively identical to

```
dd if=random.20g1 of=random.20g1.dest bs=8192
```

If you were to actually use `dd`, you can do a lot more things to test disk IO (just look at [the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html) - you can use direct IO to bypass the page cache, for example), but in the end, the IO testing you can do with `dd` is pretty limited as it's going to be sequential.  `dd` will show you close to your *best* IO performance, but it can't simulate a lot of real-world workloads that uncover the downsides of IO performance.

You need to determine more about the IO pattern your grid job actually uses - is it doing sequential reads/writes like in your test, or is it doing *random* reads and/or writes where it seeks in the file(s) to an effectively random location before doing the IO?  Random IO operations are a lot more demanding on a filesystem and underlying disk hardware - especially spinning disks. Systems that can move hundreds of MB/sec of streaming sequential IO can be crippled down to literally a handful of **kilobytes** per second by random small-size IO operations.  Especially if you're using S-L-O-W 5,000-RPM SATA disks.

It can get really bad when people who don't understand filesystems and RAID arrays set up storage.  The 1 MB filesystem blocksize you mention sure looks like you may be dealing with a storage system setup under a mistaken "bigger is always faster" paradigm.

Mixing a "bigger is always faster" paradigm with things like RAID5/6 arrays and random small block IO (such as what your grid job appears to be doing) can be a recipe for utterly horrible IO performance.

[You can use `strace` on Linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to get the actual system calls your job(s) make.  Look for calls such as `lseek`, `write`, `read`, and `pwrite` and `pread`.  That will tell you the actual IO pattern your job(s) do.

Once you get your IO pattern, you can test and benchmark actual storage performance under that pattern with a tool that comes close to duplicating that pattern. You likely need a tool that will write or read to/from random locations.  Again, assuming Linux, [you can start with `fio`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/fio).  You likely need to use the random read/write options.

Comment: Thanks for the documented answer, it's in fact a filesystem use to store a lot of huge file on a distributed fs named GPFS with RAID set up accordingly.  I will not argue on is it or not the right settings. It's not the point here. Still I will do more precise testing and see why how all this happening. My IO are more random than sequential indeed

Comment: @Kiwy I know exactly what GPFS is.  I've even done GPFS installs for IBM.  GPFS is easy to misconfigure.  Assuming it's deployed on a SAN, what are the underlying arrays?  RAID5/6?  What's the RAID segment/stripe size?  Are the LUNs built on top of the arrays properly aligned to the segment/stripe size?  Are the RAID arrays something totally incompetent like 19-disk RAID-5 with a 1 MB/disk segment size/18 MB stripe size so every write operation is a slow read-modify-write? Are the disk partitions on the LUNs properly aligned so that blocksize IO operations align with the underlying RAID array?

Comment: @Kiwy Is GPFS remote replication in use?  If so, how is it configured?

Comment: @Kiwy *I will not argue on is it or not the right settings. It's not the point here.*  That's not correct.  The configuration of the underlying storage is absolutely **critical** to the performance you get.  It's entirely part of the point.

Comment: You seems to know all this way better than me. I can't answer you regarding this for several reason. but trust me the problem is not lying on the storage part. It's widely use by others and the problem is more on the job way of doing IO. I know bad storage can hurt. but it's not the case here.

Comment: @Kiwy If you can't answer those questions, you *can't* even begin to think, "trust me the problem is not lying on the storage part", because it very well **can** be in the storage part.  The fact that your application is doing 8kb IO operations on a filesystem with an obviously mismatched 1 MB blocksize is quite indicative that your system has **not** matched the characteristics of the storage in use to the actual IO patterns of your jobs. Just try doing random small-block writes to a RAID6 LUN made up of 20+ disks - and I strongly suspect that's what you're seeing. It's way too common.